# Is there a way to share files beween Docker containers that don't exist on the host?

Tags: docker

Let's say that I have Docker containers `a` (from image `a_image`) and `b` (from image `b_image`). If `b` contains a file `/path/to/b_file` (which is present in the underlying image `b_image`), is there any way for container `a` to access it?

From searching online I can only find solutions that assume that `b_file` exists somewhere on the host, and `a` and `b` would mount it using `-v` or `--volumes-from`, but that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share docker volumes between containers, and these volumes do not need to be mapped directly to a host filesystem.

For example, if you start container_a like this:

```
docker run --name container_a -v /data ...
```

Then any files under `/data` will be available to container_b if you start it like this:

```
docker run --name container_b --volumes-from container_a ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the solution above that is correct. in addition; it may be advisable to create a third image that is you "data container" for the shared data instead of using container_b for this.